#  HorizontalScrollView inside a RelativeLayout: works fine on a 1.6+API, but not on 1.5 API

Tags: java, android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I am using a `HorizontalScrollView`  inside a `RelativeLayout`.  It works fine on a 1.6+API, but on 1.5 API the `HorizontalScrollView` does not scroll, what is the problem?

On 1.5 API (3) you can only see the first part of the `HorizontalScrollView` and there's no scrolling at all, while it seems to work fine on API4 and above.

To answer question, here's some code used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    

xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"     >   

<HorizontalScrollView
 android:id="@+id/pscroll"
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/ad"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true">      

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"       android:scrollbars="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                  <ImageButton android:id="@+id/P1"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
           <ImageButton android:id="@+id/P2"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Could you post the markup you're using to create the layout?

Comment: Just an aside, developing for pre-1.6 android is alot like developing modern apps to work on windows 98.  Sure, theres some business cases, but... at some point you should let go  :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: refined, based off of negative feedback (apparently people expect their hand to be held through this)

A scroll view is meant to contain a layout, not the reversal of that. Therefore your layout should be:

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/pscroll"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/ad" android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/P1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/P2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Please read carefully The question is specific to HorizontalScroll view not working as expected in 1.5 though working well in 1.6 API level 4

Comment: There's no reason to mark my answer down. He can substitute "ScrollView" for "HorizontalScrollView". I did read the question, the answer is that he's reversing where he's placing his layout and scrollview. The scrollview is supposed to contain a layout, which is what i alluded to here. I'm not about to give an answer that doesn't take some thought to comprehend, and you obviously did not comprehend my answer.